# Jackson/Spring deserialization with generic sub classes

Tags: java, spring, jackson, kotlin, json-deserialization

First off I am using kotlin and spring.

what I am trying to do is have a filter base class/abstract class/interface which has basically nothing. It should have two children each with their own properties. let me show some code:

```
 abstract class AxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>()

data class SingleAxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>(
        val value: T,
        val isAbove: Boolean?,
        val isMatch: Boolean
) : AxisFilter<T>()

data class DualAxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>(
        val lowerBound: T,
        val upperBound: T,
        val isBetween: Boolean,
        val inclusive: Boolean = true
) : AxisFilter<T>()
```

I wrote a serilalizer:

```
class AxisFilterDeserializer<T : Comparable<T>> : JsonDeserializer<AxisFilter<T>>() {
  override fun deserialize(jsonParser: JsonParser, deserializationContext: DeserializationContext): AxisFilter<T> {
    val oc: ObjectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec()
    val node: JsonNode = oc.readTree(jsonParser)

    return if(node.has("lowerBound"))
      DualAxisFilter<T>(
              lowerBound = node.get("lowerBound") as T,
              upperBound = node.get("upperBound") as T,
              isBetween = node.get("isBetween") as Boolean,
              inclusive = if(node.has("inclusive")) node.get("inclusive") as Boolean else true)
    else
        SingleAxisFilter<T>(
                value = node.get("value") as T,
                isAbove = if(node.has("isAbove")) node.get("isAbove") as Boolean else null,
                isMatch = node.get("isMatch") as Boolean
        )
  }
}
```

and tried to use the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation, but it doesn't work - or I can't seem to make it work.

`@Type(value = SingleAxisFilter)`, `@Type(value = DualAxisFilter)` also failed because of the generics.

Hope someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all you had to do was this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
    abstract class AxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>()

    class SingleAxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>(
            val value: T,
            val isAbove: Boolean?,
            val isMatch: Boolean
    ) : AxisFilter<T>()

    class DualAxisFilter<T : Comparable<T>>(
            val lowerBound: T,
            val upperBound: T,
            val isBetween: Boolean,
            val inclusive: Boolean = true
    ) : AxisFilter<T>()
```

and then in the JSON request object you have to provide a @class property with the full path:

```
{
    "value": 5.0,
    "isMatch": true,
    "isAbove": null,
    "@class": "com.blbla.common.SingleAxisFilter"
}
```